# Are short circuits a type of parallel circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, definition, short-circuits

Since [short circuits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_circuit) have >1 electrical pathways for current to flow, the unintended and intended pathway, I would assume that short circuits are parallel circuits and therefore current is distributed to the unintended and intended pathway based on the ratio of their resistances?

Comment: Yes, what you suggest is correct.

Comment: It depends on your system. Connect the battery poles by a wire: 1 path. Emerge it in a liquid with high ion concentration: infinite number of paths in parallel. Discharge a cloud in a thunderstorm: probably just 1 path for the plasma, but unpredictable, which one it will be this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "short circuit" would be modeled as a very low-value resistor. In order to say that the resistor was "in parallel with" some other element of the circuit, then that element would have to have two terminals, and each of the element's two terminals would have to be directly connected to one of the terminals of the "shorting" resistor.

If you have a power supply, and a transmission line supplying power to a "load," then you could argue that the "load" is a two-terminal element, and you could say that a "short" across the transmission line was in parallel with the load.

[image: diagram of a short circuit]

> and...current is distributed to the unintended and intended pathway based on the ratio of their resistances?

Assuming that the load does in fact behave like a resistor, then yes. You'd calculate the currents through the short and the load just like you'd do for any two parallel resistors.